# Compare and Select Column

Tags: r, compare

**Dataset Image:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM7t4.png]

Description:

The above image is a snapshot of the data set i am working on. I have such undefined number of sets. What i would like to do is to compare last value for DS (highlighted in yellow) for every set and select the set that has the highest DS value.

Comment: I believe you're getting downvoted because there is no image. Without it this question is not answerable.

Comment: I had included the image in the question. AlexR included the image again.

Comment: @PrinceModi You seem to have deleted some essential parts of the image markup - that is why the image didn't show up.

Comment: Why do you want to do that with R when your data is in excel? Can you show us how you brought that data to R if you did that already? Else, this looks like you'll have to prepare the data in Excel first (putting into a single table with the structure Set/Date/DS/Row). When you've done that, Excel will easily solve your task with a PivotTable.

Comment: @alexR the data is actually in R itself.. I just pasted the dataset in excel for better demonstration.

Comment: @PrinceModi In what form do you have it in R, then? Ideally post a `dput(var)` for every variable `var` you have in your workspace. If the tables are too large, a `dput(head(var))` will suffice to show the gist.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by putting all of your data into a `list`, and then using `lapply` to select the last record for each `data.frame`, and then find which `data.frame` contains the largest value.

#### generate data

I can't obtain your data, since it's saved in a picture. Instead, I generate my own.

```
set.seed(123)
x1 <- data.frame(DS = rnorm(13), y = letters[1:13])
x2 <- data.frame(DS = rnorm(13), y = letters[1:13])
x3 <- data.frame(DS = rnorm(13), y = letters[1:13])
x4 <- data.frame(DS = rnorm(13), y = letters[1:13])
list_x <- list(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

#### find max

```
find_max <- which.max(lapply(list_x, function(x) x[nrow(x),]$DS))
list_x[[find_max]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. It is giving error on my side but I got the logic.

Comment: If you could post an example of your data (following @alexR's advice) it is likely someone on SO would be able to help you with your error.